# Reading the latest document in a folder C#

Tags: c#, xml, logging

At the moment I am trying to write a console application in C# that shows all the information that is displayed by the "Startup" tab in the Taskmanager.

To get the "Startup impact" I need to read Information out of the latest XML File in the C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo directory.
I want to do this with

`XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();`

The documentname contains the SID + _Startupinfo with a number.
At every startup Windows creates a new document. This means the document name changes.
Is there a way to always get the latest document, in this case 5?

Comment: well, it sounds like you could just sort an array descending, do you need help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = (from x in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby x.LastWriteTime descending
             select x).First();

// or...
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

The above code will read the latest document from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different things you can do. I'll provide a few different solutions that you can potentially use to give you an idea.

First and foremost, you'll need to get all a list of all the files in the folder. To do that, we'll need to call `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo");`

This will give you a string array with all the files. Here's where it gets fun.

You can check the last write time of the file by calling `File.GetLastWriteTime`, then find the one with the largest write time.

Sample:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo");

var mostRecentFile = files.Select(file => new 
{ 
    File = file, 
    LastWriteTime =    File.GetLastWriteTime(file) 
})
.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTime)
.First();
```

Or you could just parse the file name. If the file will always start with "SID_" and they always increment, you can do a variety of different things to manipulate that string to get that number, and get the largest value.

I'd provide a code sample, but there's an infinite number of possibilities such as `string.Replace`, regular expressions, etc.